# Redux Post Request failed with status code 404

Tags: reactjs, redux, httprequest, axios

I am trying to do a request to my local host on my network in a redux app with axios. 
here is the request code :

```
export function createAccount(userInfo){
return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/signup`, userInfo);

        localStorage.setItem('token', resp.data.token);

            dispatch({ type: types.SIGN_UP });
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('Sign Up Error:', err.message);
    }
  }
}
```

And here is what error is displayed :

```
Sign Up Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

Comment: 404 error code means that the route you are providing is wrong. Check if your BASE_URL is correct.

Comment: ok i correct my BASE_URL now i get another error
Sign Up Error: Request failed with status code 400

Comment: 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server could not understand the request due to invalid syntax.
Are you sure you have entered a valid URL ?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause may be mismatch between the names of the sent parameters and the expected on the REDUX end (actions). Better provide the code for the reducers and the action index. In my case I got 404 on POST request and when I checked the Headers (under Network) I figured out that the Request Payload is empty. The reason was the following:

```
const data = {
      linkIdCampaign,
      linkIdMix
    }
    this.props.onAddLink(data);
```

on the front end part did not correspond to the:

```
return axios.post("http://localhost:5000/YOUR_URL", { newLink, newMix})
  .then(response => {
```

in the actions index.